# CSRF validation failed when integrate CKeditor to Flask

Tags: javascript, python, flask, ckeditor, csrf

I am integrating CKeditor to Flask to add rich text support. But when file upload feature is enabled, the post request is always failed. It should be the csrf problem. Added {{csrf_token()} directly doesn't work. Is there anyplace in CKeditor should be changed to add csrf?

```
{% block content %}
<h1>Add articile：</h1>
<form>
    <input type="hidden" name="csrf_token" value="{{csrf_token()}}" />
    <textarea name="editor1" id="editor1" rows="20" cols="80">
                This is my textarea to be replaced with CKEditor.
    </textarea>
<script type="text/javascript">
CKEDITOR.replace('editor1', {
    filebrowserUploadUrl: '/ckupload',
});
</script>
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

To handle file upload,

```
def gen_rnd_filename():
    filename_prefix = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S')
    return '%s%s' % (filename_prefix, str(random.randrange(1000, 10000)))

@app.route('/ckupload', methods=['POST', 'OPTIONS'])
def ckupload():
    """CKEditor file upload"""
    error = ''
    url = ''
    callback = request.args.get("CKEditorFuncNum")
    print callback
    print request.method
    if request.method == 'POST' and 'upload' in request.files:
        fileobj = request.files['upload']
        fname, fext = os.path.splitext(fileobj.filename)
        rnd_name = '%s%s' % (gen_rnd_filename(), fext)
        filepath = os.path.join(app.static_folder, 'upload', rnd_name)
        dirname = os.path.dirname(filepath)
        if not os.path.exists(dirname):
            try:
                os.makedirs(dirname)
            except:
                error = 'ERROR_CREATE_DIR'
        elif not os.access(dirname, os.W_OK):
            error = 'ERROR_DIR_NOT_WRITEABLE'
        if not error:
            fileobj.save(filepath)
            url = url_for('static', filename='%s/%s' % ('upload', rnd_name))
    else:
        error = 'post error'
    res = """<script type="text/javascript">
  window.parent.CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction(%s, '%s', '%s');
</script>""" % (callback, url, error)
    response = make_response(res)
    response.headers["Content-Type"] = "text/html"
    return response
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Current my workaround is to add csrf exception to this url.

```
@csrf.exempt
```

Comment: Cheers, this is a great workaround. For anyone else looking to do this, make sure have to have instantiated as such:  `csrf = Csrfprotect()` so that the decorator knows where csrf is. Also, if you're doing anything with multiple endpoints from your form (like I was) make sure to disable csrf for all of the routes in that form.

Answer (score 1):

CKEditor use AJAX to send uploads, so you can add CSRF support in this way:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    CKEDITOR.replace( "textarea-name", {
        fileTools_requestHeaders: {
            'X-CSRFToken': '{{ csrf_token() }}',
        },
    });
</script>
```

BTW, I recommend use [Flask-CKEditor](https://github.com/greyli/flask-ckeditor) to integrate CKEditor with Flask-WTF, it makes this usage easier：

```
from flask_wtf import CSRFProtect

app = Flask(__name__)

# the secret key used to generate CSRF token
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'dev key'

# enable CSRF protection
app.config['CKEDITOR_ENABLE_CSRF'] = True

csrf = CSRFProtect(app)
```